# Vuejs 3 is there a library like react-lazyload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading

I wonder in Vuejs 3, is there any library like react-lazyload: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload?. I try to find but it seems no.

I want to make the DOM of the whole component is not rendered until user scroll down to that components, the would help to reduce the time of first page load.

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're looking for are async components https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html

Comment: If it's just for visibility, not performance, you could use the concept of "cloaking": https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak

Comment: I tried many way, but as I see the best is to using Intersection Observer API. This is quite easy to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API